# PCB Circuit Design

Tags: pcb, resistance

I have been developing an high gain amplifier based circuit that amplifies the photodiode generated current and is read by an Adruino.

I have already developed and tested my results on a general purpose PCB (using soldered wires and throughhole components) and got the results I wanted.

Now I have designed and developed the same circuit on a PCB using SMD versions of the same components I used earlier, but I cannot obtain the same results.

When I measured the values of resistances on pcb using multimeter, they were not matching with the actual values. For example, a 1Gohm resistor measured out to be 33Mohm, 10kohm measured to be 1.8kohm.

I would really appreciate it if somebody could help with anything or any suggestion of what could be wrong.

I also measured the same resistance value by changing other components on a the pcb and it is getting affected by those components. This is affecting the gain of my amplifier which needs to be very high(feedback resistor=1Gohm) but is getting limited to 33Mohm.

How I can increase the value of the feedback resistor without problems?

Comment: Are measuring the resistors (resistances) in circuit?

Comment: Have you cleaned the PCB after assembling it to make sure that there is no surface contamination?

Comment: A schematic and layout drawing is really necessary to help you with this.

Comment: *feedback resistor=1Gohm* **Seriously?** Any little fingerprint, flux residue, humidity change will affect this, assuming your PCB substrate isn't already much less resistance that that already to some other trace or pin.

Comment: If you are dealing with low photocurrents  in the nA region 1Gohm may be needed.  I have built systems using similar values.

Comment: @Kashish - can you show your schematic?

Comment: @Kevein White , yes I am dealing with very very low currents. The main problem is that the same circuit design works perfectly fine on a general-purpose board(using throughole and smd components) but just behaves wierd on the pcb. Can you give your email id so I can talk to you personally?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're measuring the resistors while they're connected in the circuit. You cannot do this, because the resistance of the rest of the circuit will also affect the reading. You MUST disconnect at least one pin of the resistor to be tested before you can test it for resistance. Otherwise your readings will not be accurate.

As for the gain of your amplifier, you should use multiple stages to get the value you want.

Comment: Indeed - though a relative comparison to the same in-circuit measurement on the point to point version might be valid - the values will be different than those of the isolated components but might be somewhat consistent between the two implementations.  For the *reasonable* components, that is - as already pointed out that gigaohm is unrealistic.

Comment: Often the best approach with amplifying currents from a PD is to perform the amplification in one stage with high feedback values.  Noise and offset voltages will often be worse with multiple stage designs. Gigohm values do require extreme care with construction but can be handled.  The error due to circuit leakage may be just as bad with lower values if you only have  a few nA from the PD.

Comment: @DerStrom8 i am measuring the resistance in-circuit. Does that mean that the measured value on the multimeter may be wrong or that this value is how the resistor actually acts when in circuit?

Comment: @Kashish the reading will be inaccurate. When you measure the resistor in-circuit, you're actually measuring the resistance of the entire circuit, not the individual resistor

Comment: @DerStrom8 so does that mean that the measured value will be the effective resistance value or will the resistor anyways still behave as it original value is? I mean is the 1Gohm still behaving as 1Gohm or is it behaving as 33Mohm(as on multimeter)?

Comment: As I just said, the resistance your'e measuring is the resistance of the WHOLE circuit, not of the individual resistor. The value of the individual resistor will still be its nominal value +/- its tolerance. You can verify this by disconnecting one pin of the resistor from the circuit and THEN measuring the resistance across it. Note that not all multimeters can measure gigohms though, you're likely to get an OL reading, unless you have a very high-end meter